# Flex Geoprocessing Widget output parameter invalid

Tags: geoprocessing, flex, widget

I want to publish a ArcToolbox with a script on a Flex application as a widget. I have ArcGIS server from which I will publish it as a geoprocessing service. The tool has an input parameter which is a text file and the output parameter has to be a folder which will route the user to choose a folder on computer. When I try to publish this tool, it says that the output parameter - folder is invalid. Is it possible that the folder parameter is not supported by flex output data? Any way to do that?

Comment: probably permissions. Does SOM user have rights to the folder?

Comment: SOM? The user should be able to save the file(shapefile) in his/her desktop and the output parameter should be able to allow link to directory.